# radius can not get user password with IBM security directory server 6.4

Tags: ldap, freeradius, radius, websphere

I recently migrate IBM security directory server from 6.3 to 6.4.0.20. I follow this guideline https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/remote-migration-tds-62-sds-64. I set my radius server to connect to IBM security directory server 6.4.0.20 after I complete the migration. I get an error message.

> No "known good" password added. Ensure the admin user has permission
>   to read the password attribute

Radius uses user `cn=root` to bind IBM security directory server. Here is ldap module config in `/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/ldap`.

```
ldap {
    server = "10.1.11.56"
    identity = "cn=root"
    password = password

    base_dn = "dc=sample,dc=com,dc=tw"

    update {
        control:Password-With-Header    += 'userPassword'
    }

    user {
        base_dn = "${..base_dn}"

        filter = "(uid=%{%{Stripped-User-Name}:-%{User-Name}})"
    }

    group {
        base_dn = "${..base_dn}"

        filter = "(objectClass=posixGroup)"
        membership_attribute = "memberOf"
    }

    profile {
    }

    client {
        base_dn = "${..base_dn}"

        filter = '(objectClass=frClient)'

        attribute {
            identifier          = 'radiusClientIdentifier'
            secret              = 'radiusClientSecret'
        }
    }

    accounting {
        reference = "%{tolower:type.%{Acct-Status-Type}}"

        type {
            start {
                update {
                    description := "Online at %S"
                }
            }

            interim-update {
                update {
                    description := "Last seen at %S"
                }
            }

            stop {
                update {
                    description := "Offline at %S"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    post-auth {
        update {
            description := "Authenticated at %S"
        }
    }

    options {
        chase_referrals = yes
        rebind = yes

        timeout = 20

        timelimit = 20

        net_timeout = 10

        idle = 60

        probes = 3

        interval = 3

        ldap_debug = 0x0028
    }

    tls {
        start_tls = no
    }

    pool {
        start = 5

        min = 4

        max = ${thread[pool].max_servers}

        spare = 3

        uses = 0

        lifetime = 0

        idle_timeout = 60
    }
}
```

Here is all of the debug message. I think Radius has permission to read the `userPassword`and the entry `uid=eric.su,cn=users,dc=sample,dc=com,dc=tw`  really has an `userPassword` attribute. Radius works fine with old IBM security directory server (version 6.3). I have tried to create new VM and clone the old IBM security directory server and it also works fine. So, there are some settings on version 6.4 I was missed.

```
(0) Received Access-Request Id 15 from 10.1.3.52:53965 to 10.1.4.200:1812 length 48
(0)   User-Name = "eric.su"
(0)   CHAP-Password = 0xf030d35fa386df51091dc439ac0f226123
(0) # Executing section authorize from file /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(0)   authorize {
(0)     policy filter_username {
(0)       if (&User-Name) {
(0)       if (&User-Name)  -> TRUE
(0)       if (&User-Name)  {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ / /) {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ / /)  -> FALSE
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ ) {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ )  -> FALSE
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ ) {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ )  -> FALSE
(0)         if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/))  {
(0)         if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/))   -> FALSE
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/)  {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/)   -> FALSE
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /@\./)  {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /@\./)   -> FALSE
(0)       } # if (&User-Name)  = notfound
(0)     } # policy filter_username = notfound
(0)     [preprocess] = ok
(0) suffix: Checking for suffix after "@"
(0) suffix: No '@' in User-Name = "eric.su", looking up realm NULL
(0) suffix: No such realm "NULL"
(0)     [suffix] = noop
(0) eap: No EAP-Message, not doing EAP
(0)     [eap] = noop
rlm_ldap (ldap): Reserved connection (0)
(0) ldap: EXPAND (uid=%{%{Stripped-User-Name}:-%{User-Name}})
(0) ldap:    --> (uid=eric.su)
(0) ldap: Performing search in "dc=sample,dc=com,dc=tw" with filter "(uid=eric.su)", scope "sub"
(0) ldap: Waiting for search result...
(0) ldap: User object found at DN "uid=eric.su,cn=users,dc=sample,dc=com,dc=tw"
(0) ldap: Processing user attributes
(0) ldap: WARNING: No "known good" password added. Ensure the admin user has permission to read the password attribute
(0) ldap: WARNING: PAP authentication will *NOT* work with Active Directory (if that is what you were trying to configure)
rlm_ldap (ldap): Released connection (0)
rlm_ldap (ldap): Closing connection (1), from 1 unused connections
(0)     [ldap] = ok
(0)     [expiration] = noop
(0)     [logintime] = noop
(0) pap: WARNING: No "known good" password found for the user.  Not setting Auth-Type
(0) pap: WARNING: Authentication will fail unless a "known good" password is available
(0)     [pap] = noop
(0)   } # authorize = ok
(0) ERROR: No Auth-Type found: rejecting the user via Post-Auth-Type = Reject
(0) Failed to authenticate the user
(0) Using Post-Auth-Type Reject
(0) # Executing group from file /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(0)   Post-Auth-Type REJECT {
(0) attr_filter.access_reject: EXPAND %{User-Name}
(0) attr_filter.access_reject:    --> eric.su
(0) attr_filter.access_reject: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 11
(0)     [attr_filter.access_reject] = updated
(0)     [eap] = noop
(0)     policy remove_reply_message_if_eap {
(0)       if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message) {
(0)       if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message)  -> FALSE
(0)       else {
(0)         [noop] = noop
(0)       } # else = noop
(0)     } # policy remove_reply_message_if_eap = noop
(0)   } # Post-Auth-Type REJECT = updated
(0) Delaying response for 1.000000 seconds
```

How do I fix the problem? Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: You need to perform an LDAP search (e.g. use the `ldapsearch` tool) using the exact same bind user, base, search filter etc as FreeRADIUS is using, and then look to see if the password is there. If not then you need to fix the LDAP permissions. If it is there then you may need to alter the LDAP attribute map to get the correct attribute (unlikely if it was working on an older server).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already fix it. I use the `ldapsearch` tool to find the user entry. The entry has a attribute named `userpassword;binary`, not `userpassword`.   I don't know why it was appended `;binary`.